# How to detect whether a video is on mute via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

So far I've found out how to detect whether an audio element is paused or not, where I can use this function below (By the way please do tell me where is *aud_play_pause* function from and where I can learn more)

```
function aud_play_pause()
```

However, I have no clue how to detect whether a video is on mute, I only have the code below. By *detection*, I mean this code can run by itself without any event like clicking.

```
 if ( $("video").prop('muted') ) {
$("#m-v").removeClass('on').addClass('off');
 } else { 
$("#m-v").removeClass('off').addClass('on');
 };
```

or this, are they the same?

```
if (video.muted === true;) {    
$("#m-v").removeClass('on').addClass('off');
} else {
$("#m-v").removeClass('off').addClass('on');
 };
```

Comment: "please do tell me where is "aud_play_pause" function"? Huh? Is this not your code?

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to *aud_play_pause* from [this W3 example](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is a jQuery method. The html5 [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag does have a property [*muted*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-muted). So the two code samples are checking the same property/attribute. Refer to [this W3 page](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) for a list of all events and properties.

In the example below, we use jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event handlers to the video events. The function *checkMuteStatus* uses the code you provided and adds a few debugging output lines. It also uses [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to wait until the DOM is loaded before binding the event handler. To read more about event delegation, refer to [this jQuery page](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on the topic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').on('play pause ended timeupdate volumechange', checkMuteStatus);  
});

function checkMuteStatus() {
  var video = $('video');
  var videoById = document.getElementById('video')
  $('#console').append('prop: ', video.prop('muted') ? 'true' : 'false', ' .muted: ', videoById.muted ? 'true' : 'false', '<br />');
  if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
    $("#m-v").removeClass('on').addClass('off');
  } else {
    $("#m-v").removeClass('off').addClass('on');
  };
}
```

```css
#m-v.on {
  color: #f00;
}
#m-v.off {
  color: #0f0;
}
.float {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video src="http://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/rabbit320.webm" controls="" id="video">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here is a <a href="http://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/rabbit320.webm">link to the video</a> instead.</p>
</video>
<div class="float">
  <div id="m-v" class="on">Mute Status</div>
  <div id="console"></div>
</div>
```

It is unknown where *aud_play_pause* is defined but maybe you are looking at something like the [W3 audio example HTML/Elements/audio](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio)*

Comment: it isn't toggling the property- it is checking the status of the mute property....

Comment: okay I removed the button and added some event handlers to the function

Comment: Cheers mate, checkMuteStatus is just a sum name you give for 'play pause ended timeupdate volumechange' right? I learnt a lot from you today!

Comment: Yes - see the newly-added second paragraph, which mentions event delegation